# Trying to lock down cells in excel & office 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, active-directory, sharepoint, office365, privacy-protection

We have only sharepoint, office 365, excel 2013 - no domain.
I'm trying to lock down specific columns in an excel sheet.
When I click on 'Permissions' in 'Allow users to Edit Ranges' I type in a person and since we're not connected to Active Directory there is no way for the system to actually grant these permissions.

What to do, I also don't see this option on the web version.

Comment: If you want to lock it down per-user (instead of just locking it for all) then you need a central user permissions repository for it to check against (like an AD domain).  There's no other way for it to know who's trying to edit it.

Comment: There is no way to access the user repo @ sharepoint.com?  Ok not the answer I wanted but I suppose the answer I'll get.   Thank you

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 can you be more specific how to create `central user permissions repository`?

Comment: @pevik There's a few options depending on which OSes you want to use.  For Windows, There's lots of info on how to setup an  Active Directory domain.  ie: https://www.whitewinterwolf.com/posts/2017/09/26/how-to-create-an-active-directory-domain/  Hope that helps. :)